# Fix live view issues

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make an interactive environment in swift playgrounds using Xcode for a WWDC scholarship application.

When I run the code, nothing is being displayed on the Assistant Editor even though live view is selected.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIImageView() PlaygroundLiveViewable

var image = UIImage(named: "m.jpg")

let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
imageView.backgroundColor = .black

UIView.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: Is this a whole code? and what is PlaygroundPage?

Comment: Yes it is the whole code. It's the very begging of the application. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundsupport/playgroundpage)

Comment: You can check the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code!!

```
var image = UIImage(named: "m.jpg")

let imageView = UIImageView()

imageView.image = image

imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
imageView.backgroundColor = .black

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imageView
```